# Vite & Svelte – Build & Dev to ‘dist’ plus an alternative directory

Tags: directory, output, svelte, vite

I’m working on a combined project where I want to dump the results of the compile process into the ‘dist’ directory and another directory, possibly called ‘view’.

I’ve tried configuring the vite.config.js file by adding code to the export default defineConfig section of the code, in this case simply to dump everything in the view folder, ex:

```html
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte({
    build: {​
      outDir: "./view"
    }
  })],
})
```

I’ve also tried to use vite configuration commands in the build section and failed.

But nothing seems to work. Looking for assistance.